# Android : selectors for custom listviews

Tags: android, listview, layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/layout_bg1" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/layout_bg1" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_bg" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I am trying to use custom drawables in my list selector.Here is the error message I am getting in the first line:

> The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not
>   allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSL:The processing instruction target matching "\[xX\]\[mM\]\[lL\]" is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/xslthe-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this codes dependable your need . such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/footer_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/footer_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_black" android:state_pressed="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@layout/full_image_screen" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

Must be remember that when you access @drawable then must be include drawable image also for layout.

Comment: thanks for the answer but apparently there was some bug with eclipse,my code also worked after restarting and cleaning the project

Comment: Dear, if you help from my answer , then accept symbol click to earn 10 reputation, please

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

just add the above line at your xml or check if its duplicate there