# How to deal with [xX][mM][lL] in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

So I've got a program that is reading in large XML files, which contain multiple entries of data. So the database I'm using it for originally contained 40,000 separate entries written in XML file, but you can download one XML file that contains all the entries. However, because of this, the XML declaration element:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

is called multiple times throughout the document, and I was wondering whether there was some way of dealing with this through the use of StAX parser.

Edit: should of said that I can't properly parse through my document and read everything as it keeps returning the error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1062,6]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

because of the fact that the xml declaration is stated multiple times.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/xslthe-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed

Comment: Just to clarify though, I made a method that iterates through the document and tries to remove all elements that contains <?xml in it. However, the moment XMLStreamReader reaches the element, it throws an exception before it even allows me to deal with it. What do I do in those situations?

Comment: You can't use XMLStreamReader on data that is not well-formed XML without getting an exception.  See [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26870941/290085).

Answer (score 2):

Until you eliminate the spurious **`<?xml ?>`** declaration(s), you cannot treat the file as XML because it is not [***well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).  First treat it as text, either manually or programmatically, to eliminate the extra XML declarations before trying to parse it as XML.

For general information on all the ways the

> The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not
>   allowed.

error arises and remedies for addressing each way, see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898942/290085) (as suggested by Stefan).

Comment: `<!--Parsed @22-08-2019 11:46:12 -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` these are first line & still getting error

Comment: @AmitPanasara: The XML declaration may only appear once and ***only at the very top*** of an XML document.  Remove the comment that precedes the XML declaration to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line is called the XML prolog:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The XML prolog is optional. If it exists, **it must come first in the document**.

*It should not repeated anywhere else in the document.*

Source : [XMLProlog-W3Scools](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_syntax.asp)