# XSL works locally but not online

Tags: xml, xslt

When I try these files in my local XML previewer it renders into html fine. However on dropbox I just get a blank page.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100394705/Games/Minecraft/BMCCraft/BMCCraft.xml
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100394705/Games/Minecraft/BMCCraft/BMCCraft.xsl

I wasn't sure if transforms needed some magic serverside, so I put it on my lamp server. php-xls is enabled but the result is the same. (Either way, I'd imagine all the magic is done solely by the browser)

I've tried with relative and absolute URLs to no avail.

Comment: Well, what happens if you delete that empty line in front of the XML declaration? And yes, the transformation is done by the browser.

Comment: I agree with Mathias.  Not sure what "my local XML previewer" means, but the XSLT is [***not well-formed***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) because the XML declaration may only appear as the first thing in a file.  You should have gotten a "The processing instruction target matching “[xX][mM][lL]” is not allowed" type of [**error**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/xslthe-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a single space before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

In Location: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100394705/Games/Minecraft/BMCCraft/BMCCraft.xsl.  The errors I'm getting are all related to parsing that file, so try checking for and deleting any non-necessary white-space.