# Is it okay to have a <!-- comment --> as first line in SVG?

Tags: html, xml, svg, comments, standards

Can you have an XML comment as the first line in an SVG file? For example:

```
<!-- Timestamp 1434061994 -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg...
```

Is this against SVG spec? Or would it ever fail validation or would this cause any sort of problems I'm not seeing when implementing this in a website?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes,** it is ok to have a comment be the first line in an SVG file, **but only if there is no XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`).**

Nothing can appear before the [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl) in an XML file.  At most one XML declaration can appear in a file, and if an XML declaration is used, then it must be at the very top of the file.  Anything before an XML declaration, including a comment, prevents the XML from being [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) and should result in an error such as the [following diagnostic by Xerces-J](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889132/290085):

> The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not
>   allowed.

If a comment appears before the XML declaration, then the XML is not well-formed, and if the XML is not well-formed, the [SVG is not conforming](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#conform-ConformingSVGDocuments).

Final note:  **An XML declaration is optional.**  Unless you want to specify a version other than 1.0 or an encoding other than UTF-8, you don't have to have an XML declaration in an XML (or SVG) file.

Comment: I had a comment at the top of a couple of SVGs without the XML declaration. While these SVGs worked just fine, they didn't display properly in Bitbucket diffs until I moved the comments within the SVG tag.