# Error: The processing instruction target matching “[xX][mM][lL]” is not allowed

Tags: xml, scala

This question is a follow-up of this question:

[Error: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed)

As the answer in the question says, this error appears when an XML declaration is encountered anywhere other than at the top of an XML file.
The file I am processing does have the XML declaration twice.

The peculiar thing is, the error does not always appear. If it fails first time and I re-run the code, it passes. Sometimes, it fails 2-3 times and passes when I run it for the next time. In production environment, it has never failed, even though I am downloading the same file and using the same code.

Is there a solution to ignore the second XML declaration without editing the file manually or whatsoever?

I am using scala library "scala.xml".

Comment: Your XML not correct. To avoid such problem, it would be better to fix the input...

Answer (score 2):

Your input is not well-formed XML so you cannot process it successfully using an XML parser. Best to avoid generating it in the first place; if you can't do that, you'll have to repair the file using non-XML tools.