# Hibernate Exception while deploying on VPS server

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, vps

I am using VPS server first time to deploy my application. I have created a Hibernate Project. After Deploying it is giving me following error

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration:
>   /hibernate.cfg.xml
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2246)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:230)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:71)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:212)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:71)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:206)
>     util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:26)
>     services.HibernateServices.(HibernateServices.java:41)
>     servlet.GetShopProfile.processRequest(GetShopProfile.java:42)
>     servlet.GetShopProfile.doGet(GetShopProfile.java:77)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

To test if my database is working fine, I created a normal database connection class and it was working fine.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>-->
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <mapping class="pojo.TestClass"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Directory Structure

```
WEB-INF
    classes
        pojo
            TestClass.class
        services
            HibernateService.class
        servlet
            TestServlet.class
        util
            HibernateUtil.class
        hibernate.cfg.xml
```

We have Tomcat 7.0 installed.
Kindly help!!!

Comment: where is it located?

Comment: sir, I have edited the directory structure. Please let me know if any more information required

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301825/hibernate-could-not-parse-configuration-hibernate-cfg-xml. May be it can help

Comment: @Jeet, Thanks but  I visited that question. Didn't help.

Comment: I am re-installing  tomcat on my server

Comment: sometimes the problem is because, the dtd is not accessed. Try to see, whether you can access the dtd from the server where you are deploying it. for eg; there is no internet and then you can't access the dtd file online.

Comment: and if the above comment does not help, then can you post what dependencies you have in your project?

Comment: I solved the problem. I have posted in my answer. The solution was unexpected but it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling the tomcat on my server.
Any ways this issue can be solved by changing the DTD as suggested in questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301825/hibernate-could-not-parse-configuration-hibernate-cfg-xml)

I tried multiple solutions in my case but at last when nothing worked I reinstalled the tomcat and every thing was fine

Thanks every one for their inputs and time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding space in your commented lines?

```
<!--<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>-->
```

Replace above line with

```
<!-- <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property> -->
```

I think starting tag < after your comment start section is causing xml parsing issue.

Answer (score -1):

Change the hibernate.cfg.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: ya the hibernate configuration I am using is same

Comment: Did you change the 1st 2 lines as above?

Comment: Instead of <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> use <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">