# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ubuntu-14.04

I am making hibernate application using ubuntu trying to connect hibernate with mysql but this exception is arising. What should I have to do now to solve this?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:107)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:259)
at test.Client.main(Client.java:18)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,16]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:275)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103)
... 5 more
```

Comment: check your  hibernate.cfg.xml file, make sure this line is the first line of te file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Answer (score 3):

You have illegal symbols in hibernate.cfg.xml, probably spaces. Refer this for details

[Error: The processing instruction target matching “[xX][mM][lL]” is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Here problem is hibernate could not locate your hibernate configuration file.

Hibernate default locate your Hibernate Configuration file in your resource folder.

If your **Hibernate.cfg.xml** file in your resource folder then check below line must be exist in your HibernateUtil class(There you configured hibernate SessionFactory).

*sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();*

If your **Hibernate.cfg.xml** file in differnt location the add below line in your HibernateUtil class.

*sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/Path of your configuration file").buildSessionFactory();*