# Why Does This Error Consistently Stay

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, helper

This error is getting annoying. Can someone please fix what's wrong. Thanks!
Whenever I try to build the file. It gives me an error saying this: 
"[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.  build.xml   /HealPlayer line 1  Ant Buildfile Problem and this one: Element type "xml" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".    build.xml   /HealPlayer line 1  XML Problem

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" >
<project name="HealPlayer" default="makejar" basedir=".">
    <target name="makejar" description="Create a jar for the project">
        <mkdir dir="target"></mkdir>
        <jar destfile="target/${ant.project.name}.jar">
            <fileset dir="bin"></fileset>
            <fileset file="plugin.yml"></fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" >
<project name="HealPlayer" default="makejar" basedir=".">
    <target name="makejar" description="Create a jar for the project">
        <mkdir dir="target"></mkdir>
        <jar destfile="target/${ant.project.name}.jar">
            <fileset dir="bin"></fileset>
            <fileset file="plugin.yml"></fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add more context. This looks like an Ant File , What is the error Zach ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your first line to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Note: it needs to end in a **question mark** followed by a greater-than character.

You also need to make sure that the leading `<` is the first character in the file, i.e. no spaces in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following link. This has more information about xml tag.Also follow suggestion by @Erwin Bolwidt

[Error: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed/19898942#19898942)