# How to make an id element mandatory and in sequence?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am having an xml request for which I am trying to make tags mandatory. but positioning the tags at respective position confuses me as I am new to xml.
I am using in java with SAX parsing validation.

The xml is

```
<empRequest><id>5</id><fname>Samp</fname></empRequest>
```

If I need to check 'id' as mandatory

The following is my xsd file. I feel the proper re-positioning is need for validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="empRequest">
<xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:int">
                        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"> 
                        </xs:attribute>  
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="fname" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Kindly help me with exact xsd for the request.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `xs:sequence` tag. Additionally you are trying to allow an attribute `id` inside the element `id`. This seems not to be what you want. So assuming that the element `id` is mandatory and `fname` is not, this would be the XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="empRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="fname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: the attribute tag with 'use="required"' is not needed for the 'id' to be mandatory?

Comment: It is not needed for the element `id`. You use the `minOccurs` attribute to define that the element is mandatory. Because the default value for `minOccurs` is 1 you do not have to provide it in the schema. The attribute `use` is for attribute definitions.

Comment: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.-------Getting this exception with same xml and xsd which you shared

Comment: Seems like a different problem: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed

Comment: @VidyasagarSTGM: kenda has answered your original question correctly and more.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) his answer here and post new questions as needed rather than string matters along in the comments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use minOccurs="1" inside the element tag:

```
<xsd:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```