# Unable to retrieve data while parsing soap message with escaped xml using groovy

Tags: groovy

I try to select value of node from soap message (with gt and lt symbols) , but cant do that, i can only get body (root.Body) and other nodes are not visible, it is empty result. What i'm making wrong?
Thanks!

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil


String source=
'''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      &lt;ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse xmlns:ns0=&quot;urn:WS_CTM_People_ICEVA&quot;&gt;
         &lt;ns0:getListValues&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Person_ID&gt;PPL000000301739&lt;/ns0:Person_ID&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Submitter&gt;soehler&lt;/ns0:Submitter&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Profile_Status&gt;Enabled&lt;/ns0:Profile_Status&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Locale2&gt;en_US&lt;/ns0:Locale2&gt;
            &lt;ns0:VIP&gt;No&lt;/ns0:VIP&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Client_Sensitivity&gt;Standard&lt;/ns0:Client_Sensitivity&gt;
         &lt;/ns0:getListValues&gt;
      &lt;/ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse&gt;
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(source)

def Submitter =root.Body.GetListBy_QualificationResponse.getListValues.'*'.find { node->
    node.name() == 'Submitter'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the xml is *escaped*. In order to be able to retrieve the data property, it is required to *unescape* the xml string and pass it `XmlSlurper`.

Here is how it can be done:

```
String source='''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      &lt;ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse xmlns:ns0=&quot;urn:WS_CTM_People_ICEVA&quot;&gt;
         &lt;ns0:getListValues&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Person_ID&gt;PPL000000301739&lt;/ns0:Person_ID&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Submitter&gt;soehler&lt;/ns0:Submitter&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Profile_Status&gt;Enabled&lt;/ns0:Profile_Status&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Locale2&gt;en_US&lt;/ns0:Locale2&gt;
            &lt;ns0:VIP&gt;No&lt;/ns0:VIP&gt;
            &lt;ns0:Client_Sensitivity&gt;Standard&lt;/ns0:Client_Sensitivity&gt;
         &lt;/ns0:getListValues&gt;
      &lt;/ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse&gt;
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''

//map the unescape characters
def map = ['&lt;' : '<', '&gt;' : '>', '&quot;' : '"', '&apos;':'\'', '&amp;':'&']
//Replace them in source string
map.collect {k,v -> source = source.replaceAll(k,v)}
//Now parse it
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(source)
//Get the submitter
def submitter = root.'**'.find { it.name() == 'Submitter' }
println submitter
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5171969888616448)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But i though that XmlSlurper has already unescape chars, because output of root.Body is shown correctly.

Comment: SlavondeR, No, if you look at source string, only part of the xml is unescaped and part is escaped that is where landing it problem. Hope it did what you are looking for. [Appreciate if you can accept it as answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Rao, there is another problem, if you can help please. When i try parse soap within xml in it after unescape chars ive got error:
[Fatal Error] :1:158: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
How i can handle with it? Thanks
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><getResponsePartSRPResponse xmlns="http://upg.sbns.bssys.com/"><return>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;

Comment: @SlavondeRRave, are you using soapui? may be you can create a new question with details as much as possible. or see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed)