# How can switch on main screen after successfully login in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am new in JavaFX. I am trying to load another FXML file after successfully login:

```
<BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity"
  maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
  prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1370.0" styleClass="anchor_background"
  stylesheets="@index.css" xmlns="javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141"; xmlns:fx="javafx.com/fxml/1";
  fx:controller="properties.Admin_homepageController">
```

It's showing error in this line:

```
Parent admin_homepage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Admin_homepage.fxml"));
```

The error is:

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: file:/C:/Users/Arpit%20Singh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Properties/dist/run1802424867/Properties.jar!/properties/Admin_homepage.fxml at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)

Comment: show the relevant parts of your code as well as the error by [edit]ing the question

Comment: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Arpit%20Singh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Properties/dist/run1802424867/Properties.jar!/properties/Admin_homepage.fxml

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)

Comment: <BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1370.0" styleClass="anchor_background" stylesheets="@index.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="properties.Admin_homepageController">

Comment: I will not help at all since I do not know javafx. This issue being urgent does not matter. And please use the [edit] functionality instead of posting the information as comments.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the full stack-trace.

Comment: Pro tips: (1) don't beg for urgent/priority treatment, (2) always put all of the information readers need in the question itself, (3) don't ask for private tuition, email contact or support over Skype. All help is rendered in the open here, so as to benefit future readers. (4) Given you have questions -4/-1/-1, I expect you are hovering close to a question ban, so for your own sake, please read the links given to the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack-trace contains:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Users/Arpit%20Singh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Mulani_Properties/dist/run90454756/Mulani_Properties.jar!/mulani_properties/Admin_homepage.fxml

...

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,7]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

Now you should search for `Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.` and find this question [Error: The processing instruction target matching “[xX][mM][lL]” is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889132/4503858).

The reason is that you have other characters before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in Admin_homepage.fxml, remove them and put `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` into the first line.

Comment: How to change multiple anchorpane to click on menuItem?

Comment: How to call this type of method 
private void populateLead (ObservableList<lead_field> leadData) throws ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        //Set items to the employeeTable
        Lead_table.setItems(leadData);
    }