# How to parse xml from url

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Generally, what I want to do is parsing xml from url. This is what I have done:

1. I write the xml code on html file enclosed on <'textarea'><'\textarea'> tag:

   ```
   <textarea rows="1000" cols="200" style="border:none;">
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <data>
     <gambar>
       <id>wcl01</id>
       <url>https://1.bp.blogspot.com/- j9yARC6mAuY/Xp4aUTxe6eI/AAAAAAAAAGA/NegvRkwYdVAXhnTsrWoXYcjAzsHfR6BOQCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/Konferensi%2BIIWAS%2Bdi%2BVietnam.jpg</url>
     </gambar>
     <gambar>
       <id>wcl02</id>
       <url>https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aIkYkd3ePMY/XqDDsTMYMAI/AAAAAAAAAHA/QKZOQ8cPr_0LUfLNrYrA3w6gvNV-ao-QCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/Konferensi%2BAptikom%2Bdi%2BBandung%2B1.jpg</url>
     </gambar>
   </data>
   </textarea>
   ```

On the website, this is how it looks:

[image]

2. Then I parse the xml using this code:

   ```
   from urllib.request import urlopen
   from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
   from lxml import etree
   var_url = urlopen('https://imanparyudi.000webhostapp.com/gambar.html')
   xmldoc = parse(var_url)
   elem = etree.XML(xmldoc, parser=parser)
   ```

but I got this error:

```
    File "<string>", line unknown ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0
```

I assume that this error is caused by whitespace at the beginning of the xml code. So, I have tried to remove this whitespace using, first: etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True) and second: etree.XMLParser(recover=True) like this:

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
    from lxml import etree
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    var_url = urlopen('https://imanparyudi.000webhostapp.com/gambar.html')
    xmldoc = parse(var_url)
    elem = etree.XML(xmldoc, parser=parser)
```

and

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
    from lxml import etree
    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    var_url = urlopen('https://imanparyudi.000webhostapp.com/gambar.html')
    xmldoc = parse(var_url)
    elem = etree.XML(xmldoc, parser=parser)
```

But, both ways give the same error:

```
    File "<string>", line unknown ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0
```

3. So, my questions here are:

a. Is this problem cause by the use of <'textarea'><'\textarea'> tag?

b. If so, how can I post my xml code on a website?

c. If not, how can solve this ParseError?

Comment: Why are you not using `parse` from `lxml.etree`? Don't mix APIs. `lxml` extends Python's ElementTree API so shares many methods with `etree`. Also, please post the output of `var_url` not as screenshot. Let's see exact object you intend to `parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get back HTML doc.
Inside the HTML there is  `<textarea>` that holds the XML doc.
The code below point to the XML doc and parse it.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get('https://imanparyudi.000webhostapp.com/gambar.html')
if r.status_code == 200:
    start = r.text.find('<?xml')
    end = r.text.find('</textarea>')
    root = ET.fromstring(r.text[start:end])
    print(root)
```

Comment: Hi @balderman, it works. Thank you very much. But I have one question. What is this: r.status_code == 200 ?

Comment: The status code is the http status code that is returned from the http server. 200 means OK

Comment: Another question. In my case, I post my xml code in html using <textarea></textarea> tag. My question is: is it possible to post xml code in html without using <textarea></textarea> tag? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Just upload the xml to the website and point the browser to it

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're missing this at the beginning of the document

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

An XML declaration,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

may only appear once and only at the very top on an XML document.

Clearly, having

```
<textarea rows="1000" cols="200" style="border:none;">
```

ahead of it violates that requirement.

### Remedies

- Since you're only specifying that the XML is version 1.0, and that's the default anyway, simply remove the XML declaration, or
- Remove everything before the XML declaration.

### See also

- [Error: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889132/290085)